# How can I recover from an accidental git push -f?

Tags: git, file-recovery

I just ran `git push -f` by mistake, thus overwriting a remote branch.

Original:

```
(remote origin:)
    branch master -> commit aaaaaaa
    branch foo    -> commit bbbbbbb

(local)
    branch master -> commit ccccccc
    branch foo    -> commit ddddddd
```

After `git push -f`:

```
(remote origin:)
    branch master -> commit ccccccc
    branch foo    -> commit ddddddd
```

In my local repository, I'm working on the `master` branch, so I can restore the branch `master` to commit `aaaaaaa`, because I can get commit `aaaaaaa` from `git reflog`. However, I couldn't get commit `bbbbbbb` because I didn't pull before `git push -f`.

I have tried `git reflog` in the remote repository, but there's nothing useful in reflog in the bare repository.

How can I restore the branch `foo` back to commit `bbbbbbb` in the remote repository?

(P.S. I don't know the actual value of `bbbbbbb`.)

Comment: But the remote repo is a bare repo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reflog of HEAD will indeed be useless, but each branch also has its own reflog; if you want to recover the branch `foo`, start with `git reflog foo` (or `git log -g foo`).

Even without a reflog, Git still retains the unused objects for several days (weeks?), so you can recover by finding the commit ID in some other way and manually reattaching it to a branch:

1. Connect to the remote over SSH.
2. **Make a backup of the remote repository.**

   ```
   tar -cvzf ~/project-backup.tgz /path/to/project.git
   ```
3. Find the full-length commit ID of `bbbbbbb`. As long as you know the first few characters, you can use `git show bbbbbb` and/or `git log bbbbbb` to find out the full ID.

   ```
   $ git show bbbbbbb
   commit bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
   ```

   If you don't know the commit ID at all, then run `git fsck` and you should get a list of "dangling commits". Examine each commit using `git show <id>` and `git log <id>` until you find the correct one.
4. Update the branch references:

   ```
   git update-ref refs/heads/master aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
   git update-ref refs/heads/foo    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb...
   ```

   Manual method (less safe):

   ```
   echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa... > refs/heads/master
   echo bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb... > refs/heads/foo
   ```
5. Check with `git log master` and `git log foo` (still on the server) to make sure that you restored the correct branches to the correct commit IDs.

Comment: Thanks, I had saved the dangling branch with `git fsck`.

Answer (score 0):

- Gerrit provides server reflog through [REST API](https://gerritcodereview-test.gsrc.io/rest-api-projects.html#get-reflog).
- Github also provides [repo event log](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-repository-events). There is a [howto](https://objectpartners.com/2014/02/11/recovering-a-commit-from-githubs-reflog/) also.

It is likely other services to also provide such. It is a day-saver.